# Data structure used for implementing spreadsheets

Tags: data-structures, spreadsheet

What is the data structure used by spreadsheets program like ms-excel?

Comment: Are you interested in the means of storing the contents of the cells, or of storing and keeping track of the many cells, or both?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe, probably, a sparse matrix:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix

Answer (score 3):

While it is not exactly Excel, Open Office's Spreadsheet program is open source. It's a fairly large code base but nevertheless giving it a peek might give you a better understanding of how such an application is implemented:

http://contributing.openoffice.org/programming.html

Answer (score 3):

I got this question in an interview today.

The answer they were looking for (because I asked the interviewer at the end) was to implement a class structure that used multiple objects; formulas, references, and numerics.

Not much more detail to offer but suffice it to say that programs like google docs are much more interesting (to code) than they seem.

Answer (score 1):

I expect it to use **many**.

For example, an AST to recalculate formulas (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314943/what-algorithm-does-excel-use-to-recalculate-formulas) question).

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: That may have been the case for early spreadsheets with naive implementations that limited rows and columns to a quantity that could fit in memory, but it's doubtful any successful implementation would suffer such constraints as a 2D array would impose.  The art is to give the feel of a 2D array without actually being a 2D array.

Comment: Since someone asked me directly via email what I meant by this comment, a spreadsheet's underlying datastructure is typically a directed acyclic graph, to create a sparse array. What is seen on screen is really just the view of a traversal of the data model in a row/column order, where the row/column information is just contained within each vertex along with the payload.